# Whats the reason for "Deprecated encryption algorithm"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption

Was having a look at sys.dm_os_performance_counters to find out what deprecated features is used on my SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
SELECT [object_name], instance_name, cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE [object_name] LIKE '%:Deprecated Features%'
    And cntr_value > 0
Order By cntr_value desc
```

**Found lots of "Deprecated encryption algorithm". Cant understand why..**

In SQL Profiler i can catch "*Deprecated encryption algorithm rc4 will be removed in a future version of SQL Server[..]*", but cant really understand what T-SQL causes it. and cant find any place where is used RC4 algorithm (because of [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345262%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

There is no Asymmetric keys. Symmetric keys use AES_256 algorithm, protected by certificate, certificate is protected by DMK.

**UPDATE:**
Used advice and filtered one SPID in SQL Profiler. Found every time i use symetric key, this event is fired. TSQL:

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY MyKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate;
```

But:

```
Select key_algorithm, algorithm_desc, * 
From sys.symmetric_keys
```

For this key returns

```
key_algorithm   algorithm_desc
A3              AES_256
```

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party databases / vendor tools running against this server?

Comment: There is DB for Windows Server AppFabric.

Answer (score 1):

SSB/DBM [Endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx)?

> Specifies that the endpoint must use the RC4 algorithm. This is the
>   default.

You can get more info from the [Deprecation Announcement Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186302) and [Deprecation Final Support Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178053) Profiler events.

Comment: there is no entries in sys.database_mirroring_endpoints nor
sys.service_broker_endpoints :(

Answer (score 0):

You might have stored procedures or user defined functions with the clause [WITH ENCRYPTION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx#Encrypt).